# GTK3 multiple UI files

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk3, anjuta

I am tying to make a login form using Python and GTK3 with the help of Anjuta. So far, I have a UI file for my login section, and a form that makes an HTTP request. The class looks like this:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        window = self.builder.get_object('window')
        window.set_title("LOGIN")

        window.show_all()
        self.username = ''
        self.password = ''
```

When I fill in the correct data, the HTTP request is successful and I can see the response in the console. But what I want to do is clear the current window (UI file) and load a new one in its place. That is, without closing the actual window and opening up a new one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this ui file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Generated with glade 3.15.3 on Tue Sep 17 10:11:35 2013 -->
    <interface>
      <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.10 -->
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="row_spacing">12</property>
        <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">I'm a widget from the new content</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Me too</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
      <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">1</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button3">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">2</property>
                <property name="top_attach">2</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </interface>
```

Now, you create you your window as usual:

```
    window1 = self.builder.get_object('window2')
    window1.show_all()
```

If you want to change the content of the window. Then you need to destroy/hide the widget you want to hide.

```
    grid1 = self.builder.get_object('grid1')
    grid1.destroy()
    grid2 = self.builder.get_object('grid2')
    window1.add (grid2)
```

And we're all good to go. You can load your second widget hierarchy (*grid2*, I mean) from the same initial ui file or from a new one. What you need to understand, is that after the **Builder** create the objects from the ui files, it can't modify those further.

Comment: This is what I tried but it creates a new window and keeps the existing one.

Comment: Course it will. If you don't destroy the initial window it will keep around. The function of **GtkBuilder** is parsing the UI files and building objects. And since **GtkBuilder** allows you to *append* multiple there's no reason for destroying one object when getting a another.

Comment: Alright, I understand. So the question remains - how do I reload the UI file in the same window without creating a new one - load the second ui file in the original window?

Comment: So you want to change the widget hierarchy in your already created window ?. That would be destroying the widget you don't want and add the ones you wants, probably from another file.

Comment: Pretty much yes, that is what I want to do. In essence the idea is the following - there is a login(authentication) going over http. If the response is successful, clear the widget(form and everything in the process) and load the data from the response inside the widget(some text).

Comment: Well, that the answer above